# Phalcon Dev Tools - Builder doesn't knows where is the models directory

Tags: phalcon

I'm getting "**Builder doesn't knows where is the models directory**" error when I run the **phalcon all-models** command in both ***Command Line*** and **Phalcon Webtools**.

Please let me know what am I missing?

[image: Web Tools]
[image: Command line]

My **webtools.config.php** content

```
define('PTOOLS_IP', '216.174.134.2');
define('PTOOLSPATH', '/var/www/html/vendor/phalcon/devtools');
```

My **webtools.php** content

```
use Phalcon\Web\Tools;

require 'webtools.config.php';
require PTOOLSPATH . '/scripts/Phalcon/Web/Tools.php';

Tools::main(PTOOLSPATH, PTOOLS_IP);
```

My **config.ini** content

```
[database]
adapter  = Mysql
host     = localhost
username = test
password = test
dbname   = test

[application]
controllersDir = ../app/controllers/
modelsDir      = ../app/models/
viewsDir       = ../app/views/
pluginsDir     = ../app/plugins/
libraryDir     = ../app/library/
cacheDir       = ../app/cache/
baseUri        = /

[models]
metadata.adapter = "Memory"
```

I have change the modelsDir from **../app/models/** to **/../app/models/** but still not working.

---

**ANSWER FOUND:**

---

Going to project root directory and type the command ([instructions](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tools.html#generating-models))

```
# phalcon all-models --directory /var/www/html/projec_name
```

I speficied the --directory which is the Base path on which project will be created.

Thank you **colburton** for helping me debug this problem. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to project root directory and type the command ([instructions](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tools.html#generating-models))

```
# phalcon all-models --directory /var/www/html/projec_name
```

I speficied the --directory which is the Base path on which project will be created.

Thank you **colburton** for helping me debug this problem. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the options array you pass to the builder you need to add 'modelsDir' with the correct path.

On [this page](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tools.html) you can find a video with the webtools. There is a tab for "Configuration", where you can set them.

It is also located in the config.ini under app/config

Comment: could you please give me an example of passing values to options array

Comment: I have watched the video you mentioned, unfortunately, my Phalcon Web Tools doesn't have Configuration tab (please see screenshot in my question). What version of Phalcon Web Tools should I use?

Comment: It is also located in the config.ini under app/config

Comment: colburton: I have added the config.ini to the question, please advice if I'm missing something.

Comment: Where are your models actually located?

Comment: my models location: /var/www/html/phalconblog.northwind-traders.com/app/models

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55577/discussion-between-colburton-and-tuyen-nguyen).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Phalcon 3. After generating a project with phalcon console tool I encountered this error.

There is an easy way out to resolve this issue. Change the following settings in app/config/config.ini if you have one.

**[application]**

**controllersDir = app/controllers/**

**modelsDir      = app/models/**

**viewsDir       = app/views/**

**pluginsDir     = app/plugins/**

**libraryDir     = app/library/**

**cacheDir       = ../cache/**